# Pn junction and the structure of diodes

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics, conductors, electrochemistry

I've read the part about pn-junction from Manfred Albach's "Elektrotechnik" book and I've seen some resources online as well. However, there are a few questions that bother me and prevent me from understanding the concept clearly. Here are the questions:

1. Are p-doped and n-doped structures still neutral by themselves? This is what I am thinking, but the names seem a little bit weird, so I just wanted to be sure.
   [image: p-dope,n-dope examples]
2. When we combine these two "zones", i.e. p-zones and n-zones. We get the following structure and the graphs:
   [image: Image taken from wikipedia]

Here I understand that the neutral p-dotted structures have "holes" that behave like positive charges and n-dotted structures have electrons that they want to give away to reach to a more stable structure. (Hence, acceptors and donors.) I also understand that the material outside of the space charge region continue to be neutral. I also understand that the electrons from n-zone move towards p-zone and the holes from p-zone move to n-zone, creating the middle charged region. According to this thought process, it  makes sense that the charge volume density and electric field are zero outside of the region. My question is, why is the electric field not constant inside of these region? I interpreted this configuration as a similar structure with a parallel plate capacitor with +q one side and -q on the other side. But if it were actually like this, the field would have been constant inside the region. What should my thought process be in approaching this question?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Doping is the process of introducing impurities into a semiconductor crystal to modify its conductivity. Doping can create two types of semiconductors: n-type and p-type. N-type semiconductors have more free electrons than holes, while p-type semiconductors have more holes than free electrons. The dopants are atoms or ions that have either one or three extra electrons compared to the host atoms.

p-doped and n-doped structures are still neutral by themselves, because the impurity atoms that introduce the charge carriers are also electrically neutral. The terms n- and p-type doped only refer to the majority and minority charge carriers, respectively. Each positive or negative charge carrier belongs to a fixed negative or positive charged dopant.

A pn junction is formed when an n-type and a p-type semiconductor are joined together. The junction creates a depletion layer, which is a region where there are no free charge carriers. The depletion layer has an electric field that opposes the diffusion of charge carriers across the junction. The electric field in the depletion layer depends on the doping levels and the width of the depletion layer.

The electric field in the depletion layer can be calculated using the following formula:

$$E = \frac{\sigma}{q}$$

where $E$ is the electric field, $\sigma$ is the surface conductivity of the depletion layer, and $q$ is the elementary charge.

The surface conductivity of the depletion layer can be estimated using the following formula:

$$\sigma = \frac{2e^2}{\lambda}$$

where $e$ is the elementary charge and $\lambda$ is the width of the depletion layer.

The width of the depletion layer can be measured using various methods, such as Hall effect, Kelvin probe, or electron microscope.

The main question is not so precisely stated but this information may help.

- The electric field in the depletion region is not constant, but varies linearly from its maximum value at the junction to zero at the edge of the depletion width.
- The electric field in the depletion region depends on the charge density and the permittivity of the semiconductor material. The charge density in the depletion region is zero, so the electric field cannot change across the boundary of the depletion region. However, as we move away from the junction, we encounter a negative charge delta function at the edge of the depletion region, which creates a non-zero electric field.
- The electric field also depends on whether we are in a p-type or an n-type region, since they have different doping levels and ionization potentials. The electric field lines must be continuous across the interface between p-type and n-type regions, so they must equal each other at that point.
- The electric field in a parallel plate capacitor is constant because the plates are assumed to be infinitely large and thin, and the charge density on each plate is uniform. This means that the electric field lines are parallel and equally spaced between the plates, and there is no electric field outside the plates. The electric field is given by the formula:
  $$E = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$$
  where $E$ is the electric field, $\sigma$ is the charge density on each plate, and $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space.
  This is an idealized model of a capacitor, and in reality, the electric field is not exactly constant. The electric field near the edges of the plates is slightly distorted, and there is a small electric field outside the plates. The electric field also depends on the distance between the plates and the dielectric material between them.

To approach this question more deeply, you can use Poisson's equation to derive an expression for the electric field in terms of doping concentrations and widths. You can also use graphical methods to visualize how the electric field changes with distance from the junction.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! Appreciate it. Can you please elaborate on why the electric field in the depletion region is not constant, but varies linearly from its maximum value at the junction to zero at the edge of the depletion width?